# SOLVED: cpanel/WHM cannot terminate accounts beacuse of /etc/shadow

Tags: linux, centos-7, cpanel, whm

i couldn't find the answer after searching. when i try to terminate an account in my WHM, I face the below error

`API failure: (XID sngjqn) The system failed to lock the append-only (+a) file “/etc/shadow” (as EUID: 0, EGID: 0) because of the following error: Operation not permitted`

note: i have checked and there is no *.lock file in /etc foulder, i use CentOs-7

**UPDATE (March 21 2022):**

i have solved the problem with `chattr  command in linux with blow commands :

`chattr -a /etc/shadow`

`chattr -a /etc/passwd`

in these commands we say the files are not append-only anymore.

Comment: It is not about any lock file, `Operation not permitted` should tell you that you don't have the permissions to access the file

Comment: [Have you tried the solutions that exits on the cPanel website?](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360061879433-The-system-failed-to-lock-the-append-only-a-file-etc-apache2-conf-httpd-conf-)